# App Orientation not working in Firefox OS packaged "web" type app

Tags: javascript, json, manifest, mozilla, firefox-os

I am trying to make an app which should always work in portrait view. I usually test the app in my device by uploading all files including the manifest file in a local apache server and install it in my device by the function

```
navigator.mozApps.install(manifestURL);
```

written in install.html file.
While installing the phone is correctly detecting the manifest file and it shows up the app name developer and so on which is provided in manifest file.
But while running the app the orientation is not working well. When I rotate the device the app also gets rotated.
This is my manifest file

```
{
  "name": "MathBrain",
  "description": "Let us calculate",
  "launch_path": "/mathbrain2/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icons/icon16x16.png",
    "48": "/icons/icon48x48.png",
    "60": "/icons/icon60x60.png",
    "128": "/icons/icon128x128.png"
  },
  "type": "web",
  "fullscreen":"allowed",
  "permissions": {},
  "orientation": ["portrait"],
  "developer": {
    "name": "Your name or organization",
    "url": "http://your-homepage-here.org"
  }
}
```

Including

```
screen.mozLockOrientation("portrait");
```

in the app js file works but there are some other issues and I want to make my app work in portrait by providing it in the manifest file itself.

Comment: Do you have any repository for that?